# SQl query to get date difference in select row

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to write a sql query to which will give me result or select row from a table if the datediff is equal to 7 days or 24 days.

MY table look something like this:

**TableA:**

```
ID      ExpirationDate
```

I want to select row if `ExpirationDate-DateTime.NOW  == 7 days or 24 days`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   TableA
WHERE 
   DATEDIFF(DAY, ExpirationDate, GETDATE()) = 7 
   OR DATEDIFF(DAY, ExpirationDate, GETDATE()) = 24
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID
FROM TableA
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, ExpirationDate, NOW()) IN (7, 24)
```

Comment: it's not between, you need equl 7 or equal 24

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server the syntax `DateDiff(day, ExpirationDate, GetDate()) IN (7,24)` will do the job. For mysql you can use `DateDiff(ExpirationDate, CurDate()) IN (7, 24)`. the clause `IN (7, 24)` is equivalent to `= 7 Or = 24` etc.